# c++ pass pointer address to function

Tags: c++, dynamic-memory-allocation, calloc

I want to change array values inside a function when pass the pointer address to this function.
When I try to write to the array I receive a runtime error:

```
Exception thrown at 0x002D1D65 in interviews.exe: 0xC0000005: Access 
violation writing location 0xCCCCCCCC.
```

I know I can do it in different way but its only for my understanding.

this is the code:

```
void func(int **p){
    *p = (int*)calloc(3, sizeof(int)); //have to stay like thiis
    *p[0] = 1;  //this line work fine but I think I assign the value 1 
                //to the address of the pointer
    *p[1] = 2;  //crashing here.
    *p[2] = 3;  
}
int main() {
    int* pm;       //have to stay like thiis
    func(&pm);     //have to stay like thiis
    int x =  pm[1];
    cout << x;
    return 0;
}
```

I tried also with

```
**p[0] = 1;
**p[1] = 2;
```

but its crash as well.

What am I missing?

Comment: Since you're using C++, I suggest using `new int[3]` instead of the `calloc`.

Comment: you can change `*p[1] to p[0][1] = 1` in any case, C++ way is `int *px = new int[3] {1,2,3}; *p = px; ... delete [] *p;`

Comment: Dynamic arrays in C++ are spelled with `std::vector`.

Answer (score 7):

`[]` has higher precedence than `*`.

```
*p[0] = 1;
```

should be

```
(*p)[0] = 1;
```

Do the same with others `*p` occurences.

Comment: Or use C++ not only by tag and `cout` but `auto &arr = *p; arr[0]=1;`